# Sync Folder Between Two Servers

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008

I have an hourly PHP backup script for my MySQL Database, but now I need a way to synchronize the newest backup file in the bunch to a remote server.

Both of them have IIS installed, and both have MySQL + PHP Installed. Is there a better way I could be doing things, if there isn't a way to sync the two folders?

Comment: Possible dupes: [Folder sync application which can sync over Internet (the other machine specified by an IP)?](http://superuser.com/questions/181582/folder-sync-application-which-can-sync-over-internet-the-other-machine-specifie), [Is there a way to sync/mirror website file and database between two remote servers?](http://superuser.com/questions/420608/is-there-a-way-to-sync-mirror-website-file-and-database-between-two-remote-serve), [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

Comment: http://Dropbox.com !  :)

Comment: Can I use the folder in my batch file, as in, can I use the path to a dropbox folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is replication for MySQL which allow you to replicate your data to another MySQL server. You can even use the backup server for read-only access.

MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html